# A query over a single table is performing a full table scan

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called sales_line_item and it has over 6 million rows in it.  The table has a non-unique index on account_id.  This query is part of the dashboard showing the top 5 most ordered items.

This query below seems to take 16s.  Looking at the query plan, it seems like MySQL is doing a full table scan of the table.

I have tried creating index over the created_at field with no significant improvement.

```
from sales_line_item
where DATE(sales_line_item.created_at) between '2019-09-05 00:00:00' and '2019-09-05 09:34:45'
and account_id in (311,307,318,320,321,322,323,332,347,439,519,630,634,643)
and is_modifier = 0
and unit_price >= 0
group by sku order by sku_count desc limit 5
```

Any suggestions on what can I do to optimize this query?

Comment: Any chance you can post the execution plan? It sounds like the delay could be caused by something other than what you expect

Comment: `GROUP BY` can also cause a full table scan.  Is `sku` indexed?

Comment: This is what is basically shown in the execution plan:   select_type = SIMPLE, table - slaes_line_item, type = ALL, possible_keys = idx_saleslineitems_accountid, rows = 5983922, Extra = Using where;Using temporary;Using filesort

Comment: What is what is shown in the execution plan? Could you post it into the answer so that I can take a look?

Comment: Here is a sister query which takes just as long and gets the top five items by $sales.   ```select sku, sum(sales_line_item.total_amount) as sales_count, product_name 
 from sales_line_item where DATE(sales_line_item.created_at) between '2019-09-05 00:00:00' and '2019-09-05 09:34:45' 
 and account_id in (311,307,318,320,321,322,323,332,347,439,519,630,634,643) 
 and sales_line_item.total_amount >= 0 
 and sales_line_item.is_modifier = 0 group by sku order by sales_count desc limit 5```

Comment: Whether or not the index gets used depends on the statistics on the table.  How many rows match the `account_id` restriction?

Answer (score -1):

I was discussing with a friend who is expert in Oracle and he mentioned that I should run `analyze table sales_line_item`. He said that as the database grows, the statistics can get old and query profile is not aware of it and tries to build a plan based on the old info.  After I ran this query, the time dropped form 16+s to <1 s.  Also the query plan changed from full table scan to index range scan on account id.